# MySql Join left me with an empty table

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I made a query that list all the players on all the teams for each of the clubs in my site.

A "club" has "teams" and each team has "players", I solve the listing using this query:

```
SELECT
        Club.*,
        Teams.*,
        Players.*
    FROM
        (Club LEFT JOIN Teams ON Club.idClub = Teams.idClub)
        LEFT JOIN
        Teams ON Teams.idEquipos_Categorias = Players.idEquipos_Categorias
    WHERE
        Teams.idTemporadas = 2017
```

It works great, now I want to list just the players than "has played" from other table "hasPlay" I made this changes, but It returns empty:

```
SELECT
        Club.*,
        Teams.*,
        Players.*,
        HasPlay.*
    FROM
        ((Club LEFT JOIN Teams ON Club.idClub = Teams.idClub)
        LEFT JOIN
        Teams ON Teams.idEquipos_Categorias = Players.idEquipos_Categorias) LEFT JOIN HasPLay ON Players.idPlayer = HasPlay.idPlayer
    WHERE
        Teams.idTemporadas = 2017
```

I think I mess it up in the last join...

Any advice is well recieved

Comment: None of your queries should work because `Equipos_Categorias` is not in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Sorry @GordonLinoff that was a typo there must be `Teams` instead of `Equipos_Categorias`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt your original query works

as it contains various errors and anomalies

anyway you should avoid useless ()

and especially use JOIN on the Equipos_Categorias table eg:

```
  SELECT
      Club.*,
      Teams.*,
      Players.*,
      HasPlay.*
  FROM  Club LEFT JOIN Teams ON Club.idClub = Teams.idClub
  LEFT JOIN   Teams ON Teams.idEquipos_Categorias = Players.idEquipos_Categorias
  LEFT JOIN HasPLay ON Players.idPlayer = HasPlay.idPlayer
  INNER JOIN Equipos_Categorias  ON Teams.idEquipos_Categorias =  Equipos_Categorias.idEquipos_Categorias 
          and  Equipos_Categorias.idTemporadas = 2017
  ORDER BY Club.nombre, Equipos_Categorias.idEquipos_Categorias ASC,
      Jugadores_Equipos.categoriaJugador ASC, Jugadores_Equipos.nombre ASC
```

and as verified  by OP  uisng team table

```
  SELECT
      Club.*,
      Teams.*,
      Players.*,
      HasPlay.*
  FROM  Club LEFT JOIN Teams ON Club.idClub = Teams.idClub
  INNER JOIN   Teams ON Teams.idEquipos_Categorias = Players.idEquipos_Categorias and team.idTemporadas = 2017
  LEFT JOIN HasPLay ON Players.idPlayer = HasPlay.idPlayer
  ORDER BY Club.nombre, Equipos_Categorias.idEquipos_Categorias ASC,
      Jugadores_Equipos.categoriaJugador ASC, Jugadores_Equipos.nombre ASC
```

Comment: Thanks, @scaisEdge as I say in an early edit, that table must be replaced by `Teams`.  But in your answer you use `INNER JOIN` and I try it and works!!